# Relational algebra without aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

We have a table Phone whose values are

```
(Name, Number)
--------------
(John, 123)
(John, 456)
(Bravo, 789)
(Ken, 741)
(Ken, 589)
```

If the question is to Find the guy who uses only one number, the answer is Bravo.

I solved this using `aggregate` function. But I don't know how to solve without using aggregate function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM test
        WHERE NAME = t.NAME
            AND number <> t.number);
```

And a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faae5/3).

I'm not sure about this representation in relational algebra (and it's most likely not correct or complete but it might give you a starting point):

`RESULT = {(name, number) ∈ TEST | (name, number_2) ¬∃ TEST, number <> number_2}`

(this is the main idea, you could probably try and [have a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) to try and rewrite this correctly, since I haven't written anything in relational algebra for more than 10 years).

Or maybe you're looking for a different type of representation, [like this one here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/btr/bioinformaticsschool/slides/gehrke.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and use the same table in your `JOIN` , something like this..

```
    SELECT a.NAME, a.NUMBER FROM test a 
    LEFT JOIN test b ON a.name = b.name AND a.number <> b.number
    WHERE b.name IS NULL;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you are using Access-SQL -

```
SELECT Name
FROM Phone
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) = 1;
```

Otherwise, try -

```
SELECT Name
FROM Phone
WHERE COUNT(Name) = 1;
```

If you have any questions, then please feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of RANK() functions something like below.

```
SELECT * FROM @Tbl WHERE Name NOT IN(
SELECT Name FROM (
SELECT  Name, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) AS Rank
FROM @Tbl) t
WHERE t.Rank > 1)
```

The only draw back of this method is, you need to use unique id from your table to get the right result.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f5c8/2)

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing it is:

```
select Name from Phone p
where (select name from Phone p2 where p.name = p2.name and p2.number <> p.number limit 1) is null
```

Edit: added limit 1 to make sure sub select returns a scalar

Comment: An empty result set is not the same as NULL, since I'm expecting the `SELECT` in your `WHERE` to return "nothing", correct?

Comment: I guess you might be right. Maybe it's just worikng because PostgreSQL is nice to me and assumes a scalar when I use "is null"

Comment: Could be, I haven't worked with PostgreSQL, mostly SQL Server. Also, limiting to 1 would have no point, if you're expecting the result of your `SELECT` to be nothing.

Comment: Without limit 1 we might get a result set back rather than a scalar (e.g. if we added one more number to John), and then the query would fail, even in PostgreSQL.